# How do I run dna.sh from cygwin?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, cygwin

I downloaded a dna.sh off of Github, and I can't seem to get it to work on cygwin.
When I use the command,

```
sh dna.sh
```

, I get the error,

```
 : No such file or directory
dna.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found 
dan.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r' '
'na.sh: line 9: `for j in f b; do
```

The contents of the dna.sh are here: https://github.com/jaykru/colorscripts/blob/master/dna.sh

Comment: Search [with this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%24%27%5Cr%27%3A+command+not+found%22+is%3Aquestion) for other similar cases.

Comment: try to do a `dos2unix sna.sh` or `fromdos dna.sh`

Comment: Are you sure you have copied the content right way.. because it works for me.

Comment: I wonder how much money the extra `\r` in Windows line endings has cost the IT industry?

Comment: have you tried `bash dna.sh` or just `./dna.sh`? maybe `sh` in cygwin is not linked to `bash` like it is on linux systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you write your file in Windows and now are executing it in Cygwin? Please, don't tell me you used `Notepad.exe`.

*dope slap!*

Your problem is that Windows puts a Carriage Return and a Line Feed character at the end of each line `\r\n`. However, Unix (and Cygwin) insist that the correct line ending combination is a mere Linefeed `\n`.

Use a real program editor to write your programs. Don't use Notepad. Download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) and set it to use LF (Unix line endings) on all your shell scripts. Or, learn to edit your files in Cygwin. You can use VIM or gmacs (gmacs is a great operating system. Too bad there's no editor with it. //old [Editor war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war) joke//).

Actually, there are a variety of [GUI editors on Cygwin](http://www.everyjoe.com/2008/12/26/technology/many-cygwin-text-editors-2/) too, but you have to get X11 working.

You can try `dos2unix` on Cygwin -- if you've installed it.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right. I knew I shouldn't use Notepad.exe, but I didn't know I had to set Notepad++ to LF.